# How to reduce the radius of the avatar generated using auro_avatar flutter package?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I have used [auro_avatar 0.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/auro_avatar) for generating avatar from `User FullName` but I am not able to reduce the size of the circle avatar. I want to put this on AppBar.

```
new InitialNameAvatar(
    'Rahul Kumar',
    circleAvatar: true,
    borderColor: Colors.grey,
    borderSize: 1.0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    padding: 2.0,
    textSize: 5.0,
),
```

It is not working even when I reduced padding. Please Help

Comment: You can simply make your own custom widget like that without using packages which even have maintenance rating at 36.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you can wrap `InitialNameAvatar` by `Container` widget, then you can add `width` and `height`. I tried this and it works.

```
  Container(
            width: 35.0,
            height: 35.0,
            child: InitialNameAvatar(
              name,
              circleAvatar: true,
              borderSize: 2.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
              padding: 5.0,
              textSize: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look into package that it has radius of 40. you can change radius there or can create a variable and assign that variable value as a radius, so you can dynamically change radius.

Note: If you make changes like this in package then you will no longer get updates of that package.

Second option could be copy that file code and add in your local file, while will become your code, so you can make any changes you want. This option is more solid in this case.